# Concurrency - Conditional synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading two text files concurrently line by line.

What I am specifically want to do is when the `lineCount` on each thread are the same I want to take a look at the string that the scanner is currently reading.

I looked around for certain pattern I can implement like [Compare and Swap](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/compare-and-swap.html) and  [Slipped Condition](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/slipped-conditions.html) but I cannot wrap my head around how it would help me achieve my goal. I am new to concurrency programming.

What I have managed so far is to synchronize the string reading and printing with `counterSync` method and I know that I have carry out my thread lock/pause operation there and take a look at the string.

```
public class concurrencyTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filePath1 = "path1.txt";
        String filePath2 = "path2.txt";
        reader reader = new reader();
        MyThread source = new MyThread(reader, filePath1);
        MyThread target = new MyThread(reader, filePath2);

        source.start();
        target.start();
    }
    static public class reader {
        void read(String filePath) throws IOException {
            readFile(filePath);
        }
    }

    static synchronized void counterSync(String thread) {
        System.out.println(thread);
    }

    static class MyThread extends Thread {
        reader reader;
        String filePath;

        MyThread(reader reader, String filePath) {
            this.reader = reader;
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                reader.read(filePath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    static void readFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        Scanner sc = null;
        int lineCount = 0;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                lineCount++;
                System.out.println(lineCount + "===" + sc.nextLine());
                counterSync(sc.nextLine());
            }
            if (sc.ioException() != null) {
                throw sc.ioException();
            }
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if (sc != null) {
                sc.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this mean, specifically:  "when the lineCount on each thread are the same"? You don't count any lines.

Comment: inside the ```readFile``` method, I am counting the lines the scanner are reading with ```lineCount``` variable. Thus, when the lines count on each thread meet a certain condition, ex. equal to each other or a certain line number, I want to interrupt and take a look at the string **both** scanners are reading.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the "certain condition" is fulfilled for each of your threads at different time?

Comment: @Roberto Manfreda , yes I know this a very complex way to do it but I am using text files here to simplify the example. In my application, I will be reading a string streams that potentially has 10 - 100 milllion lines and I want to take a look and compare the two string at certain positions.

Comment: @M. Prokhorov, can I create sync block where it's checking the count from both threads and if one line lineCount is greater than the other, wait until the other thread catches up?

Comment: @Timothy Cymberland Do you want to stop two different threads that are reading on two different files on given number rows? Did I get right? For example thread1 is reading file1 and thread2 is reading file2. When thread1 reach the line 7 do you want to thread 2 that reads line 11 and compare the two lines? right?

Comment: @Roberto Manfreda yes! that's exactly correct! The condition can be an offset like your example or can be at the same line or at a specific line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what you are looking for is a little bit complex but still possible.
Your question lacks of some examples so correct me if I'm wrong in something.

---

You have 2 threads:

- thread1
- thread2

---

and 2 files:

- file1
- file2

Content of file1:

```
file1  
file2  
file3  
file4  
file5  
file6  
file7  
file8  
file9
```

Content of file2:

```
file11  
file22  
file33  
file44  
file55  
file66  
file77  
file88  
file99
```

---

You want to stop all threads on the same line numbers and do some oeration with the output.

---

This is the thread implementation for reading the files, we will instantiate 2 instance of it, each instance will manage a file.

```
static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
    private File fileToRead;

    public final Object lock = new Object();
    private String currentLine;
    private AtomicInteger lineCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public ReaderThread(File fileToRead) {
        this.fileToRead = fileToRead;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            try {
                Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Path.of(fileToRead.getPath()));
                lines.forEach(line -> {
                    currentLine = line;
                    // Here's your logic on different lines
                    if (lineCount.get() == 4 || lineCount.get() == 5 || lineCount.get() == 6) {
                        try {
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    lineCount.getAndIncrement();
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getCurrentLine() {
        return currentLine;
    }

    public boolean isLocked() {
        return getState().equals(State.WAITING);
    }
}
```

---

Then we will use an helper thread to notify the reader threads when our elboration will be ok:

```
static class HelperThread extends Thread {
    private List<ReaderThread> threads;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (threads.stream().allMatch(ReaderThread::isLocked)) {
                System.out.println("next line:");

                threads.forEach(thread -> {
                    synchronized (thread.lock) {
                        System.out.println(thread.getCurrentLine());
                        thread.lock.notify();
                    }
                });

                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }

    }

    public HelperThread(List<ReaderThread> threads) {
        this.threads = threads;
    }
}
```

---

Finally the main class for testing all:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f1 = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("file1.txt")).getFile());
    File f2 = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("file2.txt")).getFile());

    ReaderThread t1 = new ReaderThread(f1);
    ReaderThread t2 = new ReaderThread(f2);

    HelperThread helperThread = new HelperThread(List.of(t1, t2));

    helperThread.start();
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

---

Executing the program will result in this output:

> ```
> next line:
> file5
> file55
>
>
> next line:
> file6
> file66
>
>
> next line:
> file7
> file77
> ```

---

Here's the complete list of imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
```

---

Please note: this is a rude example, you need to manage with the correct shutdown of the threads, some modifiers are public so encapsulate it following the java guidelines, coorrectly manage all exceptions and do some general refactor.

---

---

If you want a more versatile implementation, to interpolate different lines, the following should be ok:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f1 = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(Main2.class.getClassLoader().getResource("file1.txt")).getFile());
        File f2 = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(Main2.class.getClassLoader().getResource("file2.txt")).getFile());

        ReaderThread t1 = new ReaderThread(f1);
        ReaderThread t2 = new ReaderThread(f2);

        HelperThread helperThread = new HelperThread(List.of(t1, t2));

        helperThread.start();

        t1.setName("Reader1");
        t1.setName("Reader2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
        private final File fileToRead;
        private final Object lock = new Object();
        private final AtomicInteger lineCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
        private String currentLine;

        public ReaderThread(File fileToRead) {
            this.fileToRead = fileToRead;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Path.of(fileToRead.getPath()));
                    lines.forEach(line -> {
                        currentLine = line;
                        lineCount.getAndIncrement();
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void lock() throws InterruptedException {
            this.lock.wait();
        }

        public void unlock() {
            this.lock.notify();
        }

        public boolean isLocked() {
            return getState().equals(State.WAITING);
        }

        public Object getLock() {
            return lock;
        }

        public AtomicInteger getLineCount() {
            return lineCount;
        }

        public String getCurrentLine() {
            return currentLine;
        }

    }

    static class HelperThread extends Thread {
        private List<ReaderThread> threads;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                threads.forEach(t -> {
                    try {
                        if (t.getName().equals("Reader1") && t.getLineCount().get() == 3) t.lock();
                        if (t.getName().equals("Reader2") && t.getLineCount().get() == 4) t.lock();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

                if (threads.stream().allMatch(ReaderThread::isLocked)) {
                    System.out.println("next line:");

                    threads.forEach(t -> {
                        synchronized (t.getLock()) {
                            System.out.println(t.getCurrentLine());
                            t.unlock();
                        }
                    });

                    System.out.println("\n");
                }
            }

        }

        public HelperThread(List<ReaderThread> threads) {
            this.threads = threads;
        }
    }

}
```

---

Be sure that the HelperThread starts before the other threads or it's possible to loose some data.

Comment: thank you! This will takes time digest. Is it wrong to say that this is an elaboration of the "Compare & Swap"? On a side note, you're using Stream to read the file. Is this equivalent to Scanner? It's one line compared to 15+ lines if scanner is used.

Comment: I found an interesting article basing on your question. Maybe this can remove your doubts, take a look https://www.happycoders.eu/java/how-to-read-files-easily-and-fast/.

Comment: Speaking about your question on Compare And Swap, the work here is done simply using the java.util.concurrent.atomic package. Using AtomicInteger and AtomicReference we are implicitly making use of CAS.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't post a *complete* example.  But, a few general comments:

You might be able to get away with using "compare-and-swap" logic for an *integer,* but you should not expect it to work for a more-sophisticated thing like a Java "String" or any sort of container.

You should simply use the synchronization-objects provided in the language.  If you are going to update *or even to examine* a shared data structure, you must be holding the proper lock.

Of course, "thread-safe queues" are very helpful in many designs because they facilitate the most-common activity – message-passing – and allow the various threads to operate graciously at slightly-varying speeds.  You still have to lock anything that's shared, but nonetheless it's a useful design that's really as old as the Unix® "pipe."

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "you should not use CAS for String". `String` is immutable, it's perfectly fine to CAS on references of it.

Comment: @Mike Robinson I would be doing the CAS on an integer because i am looking to sync ```lineCount``` it should be ok. Also, please elaborate on why it's not a complete example. This the exact code I am working with and it's functional...

Answer (score 1):

You can use

### [java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

> A synchronization aid that allows a set of threads to all wait for
>   each other to reach a common barrier point. CyclicBarriers are useful
>   in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must
>   occasionally wait for each other. The barrier is called cyclic because
>   it can be re-used after the waiting threads are released.
>
> A CyclicBarrier supports an optional Runnable command that is run once
>   per barrier point, after the last thread in the party arrives, but
>   before any threads are released. This barrier action is useful for
>   updating shared-state before any of the parties continue.

Here is an example using this class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filePath1 = "path1.txt";
    String filePath2 = "path2.txt";

    ReaderThread reader1 = new ReaderThread(filePath1);
    ReaderThread reader2 = new ReaderThread(filePath2);

    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(2, () -> {
        //processing when condition met in both thread
        List<String> lines1 = reader1.getLines();
        List<String> lines2 = reader2.getLines();
        System.out.println(lines1.get(lines1.size() - 1) + " " + lines2.get(lines2.size()-1));
    });


    reader1.setCyclicBarrier(cyclicBarrier);
    reader2.setCyclicBarrier(cyclicBarrier);

   reader1.start();
   reader2.start();
}


public static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;
    String file;
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    public void setCyclicBarrier(CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
    }
    public ReaderThread(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file))) {
            String line = null;
            for (int i = 0; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; i++) {
                lines.add(line);
                //condition do something
                if (i % 10 == 0) {
                    cyclicBarrier.await();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public List<String> getLines() {
        return new ArrayList<>(lines);
    }
}
```

And output:

```
this is from file1 1232123321312 this is from file 2 1232123321312
this is from file1 1232123321312 this is from file 2 1232123321312
this is from file1 1232123321312 this is from file 2 1232123321312
```